# Bootstrap 3 .control-label width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this kind of form in bootstrap 3 (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2052/)

```
<div class="container-full">         
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
        <input id="name" value="Johnatan Dodsworth" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="language">Based On</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="language">
            <option selected>English</option>
            <option>German</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="language">Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="language">
            <option selected>English</option>
            <option>German</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"> <span class="k-icon k-si-plus"></span> Add</button>
    </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

I think i have problem with `.control-label` because my form does not goes to the middle of the screen, and i can not adjut button to line in with last select input?
Or just aligh form in the middle of the page, i have tried to change col-md and everything!
What is witdh of `.control-label` class?
Does anybody have solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the width of .control-label, it's the width of the columns, the bootstrap 3 default grid has 12 columns, if you assign col-XX-6 to .control-label it gets the first 6 colmuns (to the middle of the screen), and the same thing happend with the inputs.

you can also use text-align:center on the button container to make it centered.

[See it on bootply](http://bootply.com/108623)

```
<div class="container-full">         
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input id="name" value="Johnatan Dodsworth">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="language">Based On</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select id="language">
            <option selected="">English</option>
            <option>German</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="language">Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select id="language">
            <option selected="">English</option>
            <option>German</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12 centered">
        <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary "> <span class="k-icon k-si-plus"></span> Add</button>
    </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Great this is the best soution, just one thing is is possible to align txt in control label to left side of the box?

Comment: Cool! use `3` & `9` instead of `2` & `10` solve my lable issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'form-control' to your input and selects..

http://bootply.com/108625

Comment: Yes.. it's going out the right side of the `col-md-9`. Where do you want it to go?

Comment: If you want it centered, just change it to `col-md-12`, and use the Bootstrap `center-block` class (no need for custom CSS). I updated the Bootply http://bootply.com/108625